# iOS - How - startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges works

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

How the iOS system trigger the method `-startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`?

Will the system trigger this automatically?

What if I want every 500m trigger the `-startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` how can I set my locationManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. call locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() will update your `didUpdateLocations`  method when iOS detect location update approximately 500 meters.
2. System will call this automatically until you explicitly call stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
3. iOS give his best to provide this you don't have to do anything

For more [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service)

Comment: Thanks, you mean I cannot call or set SignificantLocationChanges by myself. It all depends on system call, right?

Comment: yes, after calling locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() iOS will take care the rest.

Comment: @DeanLee you can accept my answer if found helpful.